# How to read complex lua table using c code

Tags: c, lua

I'm starting in the world of lua currently I'm creating table readings using C code

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Consume = 
{
    Consume_first = {
        Value = 100
        Request = 200
    },
    Require_var = {
        Enable= true
        Name = "Am"
    
    }
}
```

I would like to know some information

**Consume** is defined as `lua_getglobal(L, "Consume")`;

**Value**, **Request**, **Enable** and **Name** would the `lua_getfield` function be used?

Example:

`lua_getfield(L, 1, "Value")`

And in **Consume_first** and **Require_var** what should I use to define them?

My code:

```
void read_table(void) {
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "table.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        ShowError("Error reading 'table.lua'\n");
        return;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "Consume");
    .... 
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "Value");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "Request");
    ....
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "Enable");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "Name");

    lua_close(L);
    printf("Read Table complete.\n");

}
```

I'm using lua 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "Consume");

// Get Consume.Consume_first
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Consume_first");

// Get Consume.Consume_first.Value
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Value");

// Get Consume.Consume_first.Request
// Note that currently Consume.Consume_first.Value is on the stack
// So Consume.Consume_first is at index -2
lua_getfield(L, -2, "Request");
```

If you are confused with the index, you can also use `lua_gettop` to help.

```
lua_getglobal(L, "Consume");

// Get Consume.Consume_first
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Consume_first");
int Consume_first_index = lua_gettop(L);

// Get Consume.Consume_first.Value
lua_getfield(L, Consume_first_index, "Value");

// Get Consume.Consume_first.Request
lua_getfield(L, Consume_first_index, "Request");
```

Comment: Just a question. Would the `lua_getfield` index for **Require_var** have a value of **-2**?

Comment: No If you would follow this, the index is -4, `-1 => Request; -2 => Value; -3 => Consume_first; -4 => Consume`.

Comment: Got it, I'll read more about the lua index.