# Error occurs attempt to index field in lua_getfield

Tags: c, lua

I have a lua code where it is showing index error the error occurs when reading **result**

I'm using `lua_gettop(L)` for the index

My table is:

```
Avatar = 
{
    one = {
        vals = 51,
        result = 300,
    }
}
```

My code is:

```
void read_test(void) {
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        printf("Error 'test.lua'\n");
        return;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "Avatar");

    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), "one");
    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), "vals");
    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), "result");


    lua_close(L);
    printf("Read complete.\n");

}
```

When reading the table, an error occurs

`lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), "result");`

attempt to index field

What is the correct way for me to work this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read complex lua table using c code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527605/how-to-read-complex-lua-table-using-c-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lua
    lua_getglobal(L, "Avatar");

    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), "one");
    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), "vals");
    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), "result");
```

Each of these [`lua_getfield` calls](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#:%7E:text=function%20was%20set.-,lua_getfield,-%5B%2D0%2C%20%2B1%2C) pushes a new item onto the stack. First you push `Avatar`, then you index into that the `one` field, then the `vals` field, but the last line is effectively trying to read `Avatar.one.vals.result`, which does not exist.

You probably need to call `lua_remove(L, -1)` to pop the top of the stack (`vals`) before your last line that attempts to index `result`